# Can't link jQuery to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found related articles here but none of them were useful. I am learning jQuery from codecademy and when I try to practice it by myself nothing happens. 
HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Result</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='MovieSiteStyle.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='MovieSiteBehavior.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
div {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background-color: #FA6900;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

and Javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div').click(function() {
    $('div').fadeOut('slow');
});
});
```

There should appear an orange rectangle and when u click it it should disappear, but in fact it only appears and I can't make it disappear. (same example on codecademy works just fine) 
P.S some people blame me for bad question and if you think this is a bad one please explain why.

Comment: You need to include the `jquery` library. It's not there.

Comment: @Dekel how can I do that? in codecademy sample there is no jQuery included.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/211/getting-started-with-jquery#t=201701031645371721066

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add the jQuery library.
That's why it doesn't work.
Try to add :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

into the `<head>`

Answer (score 2):

Look like you forgot to add *jQuery library* - works fine. A suggestion would be to use `$(this)` inside the click listener so that you hide the *same div* that you have clicked - see demo below with *2 divs*:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #FA6900;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<br/>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of your `<body>` tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Result</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='MovieSiteStyle.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='MovieSiteBehavior.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script> 
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div').click(function() {
              $('div').fadeOut('slow');
            });
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @KingThranduil Did you have your javascript below it, inside the script tags as my edit shows?